# GitHub Pages cannot load pages

Tags: github-actions, github-pages, vite

I use `vite` to bundle my project, deploy it to GitHub, and would like to use GitHub Pages to load it. For deployment, I use GitHub Actions to deploy my project. But when the page is opened, it is blank and shows this error on the network tab and the error message on the console:

> failed to load resource the server responded with a status of 404

I understand the reason for this issue, but can not find a proper solution. Could someone suggest any?

[image: 404 screenshot]

I search online to try to find a solution, like editing `vite.config.ts`, adding `base`, or changing the absolute path and relative path for my `main.tsx`. But the deployed GitHub Pages still be blank. I expect that the project can show on my GitHub Pages.

Comment: What do the logs of the deploy workflow say?

Comment: The logs of the deploy workflow doesn't show any error.

Comment: @Oscar: if this is a public repo, please add its link to your question. That would be helpful for others to go through all the relevant details. If it's not, please add the relevant workflow and other relevant configuration. Thanks!

Comment: And when you say "use GitHub Actions to deploy it", are you talking about the built-in `pages-build-deployment` workflow, or a custom workflow?

Comment: @Azeem Thanks! The repo's link is https://github.com/oscarwang913/sales-tool and the site is https://oscarwang913.github.io/sales-tool/

Comment: @BenjaminW. Yes, it built-in page-build-deployment.

Comment: To tell GitHub that you're not trying to deploy a Jekyll site, try dropping an empty file named `.nojekyll` in the top-level directory.

Comment: @Oscar: Just checked https://oscarwang913.github.io/sales-tool/ and it's working fine. No more 404. Fixed already?

Comment: @Azeem: Yes, I've build on local and push to remote. It works. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

### How to deploy a vite app to github pages with a custom domain name.

#### Setup

1. Change (or add if it isn't there) your base urn of your repository in your vite.config.js file.

[image: repoName base config]

2. Build your application.
3. Push your application.

#### Jkelly

1. Create the appropriate jkelly file in your **repo**, settings, **Pages** tab (be carefull on changing the branch name, must be the same as yours).
   [vitejs jkelly file config](https://vitejs.dev/guide/static-deploy.html#github-pages)

#### Pull

1. pull  your project again, so you'll get the latest created files (created by the deployement pipeline).

#### Choose new base

1. Change your base inside your vite config file again (according to what your domain name is and what urn you want to set).
   If you want your project to be served at the base of your website **'/'** or on a subpage **'/subpage'** set your base accordingly.
   [image: subPage vite config base]

If you want to serve at the base, you can also just remove the base property entirely.
[image: no subPage vite config base]

2. **The link of your images have to be in the public folder and like this :** **'img/temp/example.png'**. No **'/'** at the beginning.
3. **Your favicon.ico file must be in your public folder and referenced like this in your index.html** : **'/favicon.ico'**.
4. Don't forget to delete the **/dist** folder reference in your .gitignore if it is there.
5. Build the changes and then push everything.
6. Go to your repo, **settings**, **Pages** tab, set your **Custom Domain** and save.

#### Verify your domain

*nb : steps can be found here --> [github docs / verify domain](https://docs.github.com/en/pages/configuring-a-custom-domain-for-your-github-pages-site/verifying-your-custom-domain-for-github-pages#verifying-a-domain-for-your-user-site)

1. Go to your DNS record of your domain.
2. Add the proper CNAME record : host = **[www.domain.com](http://www.domain.com)** and data = **github-username.github.io**.
3. Follow this link : [Github/settings - configure a domain](https://github.com/settings/pages)
4. Add your domain and configure it accordingly. It's gonna look something like this in your DNS records :
   [image]

You're all set . Finally... you can get some rest.

## Edit :

Note that react router has changed a lot in the past few years. It can be source of a lot of bugs so here's a step by step guide on youtube :
https://youtu.be/uEEj2c3_ydg?si=NuxLpJN5pcYYfKq8